# What is the preferred way to store state between init and update for custom knockout binding?

Tags: knockout.js

Currently I am storing the state using jQuery data for the dom element.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.customValue = {

    init: function init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var state = { isEditing: false };        
        $(element).focus(function focus() {
            state.isEditing = true;
        }).blur(function blur() {
            state.isEditing = false;            
        }).data("customBinding", state);

    },

    update: function update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // ignore if updating
        if (!$(element).data("customBinding").isEditing) {
            // handle update if they are not updating                                
        }
    }

};​
```

Is there a better place to store state per binding that does not require the dom?  Can the bindingContext be used to store state for the each instance of the binding?

Comment: Good question. I guess your solution is very good. Further enhancements might be done considering some other specifics of your code.

Comment: I second that. Every binding is related to a specific dom node, therefore storing related data bound to that dom node is a good way to go.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The `bindingContext` is a possibility, but only for passing data from `init` to `update` the first time that the binding is triggered.  The next time that `update` fires it would no longer be there.

There are really two choices for where to store this type of state:

1- On the element, as you stated.  You can use jQuery's `$.data` or KO includes APIs for doing this as well `ko.utils.domData.get(element, key)` and `ko.utils.domData.set(element, key, value)`.

2- Put this type of information in your view model, if appropriate.  A flag to indicate `isEditing` is not necessarily out of place in a view model.  I personally like to put this type of "meta-data" as sub-observables off of an observable like:

```
var name = ko.observable("Bob");
name.isEditing = ko.observable(false);
```

You would be able to bind against `name` and `name.isEditing`.

This has some advantages:

- keeps the view model fairly clean, as you are not introducing new top-level properties
- keeps the sub-observable tied to its parent observable (no need for `nameIsEditing`, etc.)
- when turned into JSON with something like `ko.toJSON` the `isEditing` sub-observable will simply be dropped when its parent is unwrapped.  So, you won't be sending unnecessary values back to the server.
- in this case, it can also have the advantage of being available for other calculations in your view model or to bind against multiple elements in your UI.

Comment: Am I missing something but if you declare the isEditing as observable and then you checked for the value of this observable in the update function of the binding, you will create a dependableObservable and then when you will change the value of isEditing to true in the init function just before changing the value of the bounded observable, isEditing will trigger a change that will force to call the update function of the custom binding. If I declare isEditing as a simple JS variable, your solution works perfectly.

Comment: why is domData better than $.data ? because it's part of ko or for some other reason?

Answer (score 10):

Attaching data to the element is fine, and Knockout uses this method internally for the control-flow bindings (if, with, etc.), for example.

Another method is to only use the `init` function and use a computed observable to handle updates. I use this method in my [repeat](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat) binding. Here are the important parts:

```
ko.bindingHandlers['repeat'] = {
    'init': function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        ...
        // set up persistent data
        var lastRepeatCount = 0;
        ...
        ko.computed(function() {
            var repeatCount = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            ...
            // Remove nodes from end if array is shorter
            for (; lastRepeatCount > repeatCount; lastRepeatCount--) {
                ...
            }
            ...
            // Add nodes to end if array is longer (also initially populates nodes)
            for (; lastRepeatCount < repeatCount; lastRepeatCount++) {
                ...
            }
        }, null, {'disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved': placeholder});
        ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I often use this pattern:

```
define(['knockout'], function(ko) {
  var interInstanceVariable = null;

  function Tree(element) {
    var privateInstanceVariable = null;

    function privateInstanceMethod() {}

    this.publicInstanceMethod = function() {}
  }


  ko.bindingHandlers.cannDendrogram = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
      $(element).data('tree', new Tree(element));
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
      var tree = $(element).data('tree');
      tree.publicMethod();
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question is old but I stumbled here looking for the approach so thought I'd chip in on a more modern ko method.

You could simply add properties to the bindingContext.$data directly. I chose an annoying variable name, "___IsEditing", to avoid potential collisions, but you get the idea...

```
ko.bindingHandlers.customValue = {

init: function init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    bindingContext.$data.___IsEditing = false;        
    $(element).focus(function focus() {
        bindingContext.$data.___IsEditing = true;
    }).blur(function blur() {
        bindingContext.$data.___IsEditing = false;            
    }).data("customBinding", state);

},

update: function update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    // ignore if updating
    if (bindingContext.$data.___IsEditing) {
        // handle update if they are not updating                                
    }
}
```

};​

Comment: if $data is the view model of the binding context, did you just add a property to your view model that will get serialized out when you do a ko.toJSON()?

Answer (score -2):

I use an function to create an common scope for init and update, by defining the common data inside the function.